# World background image issue

Tags: materials, world

For some reason I can't seem to find any of the options to make the image I've selected a world background image in blender (2.76).  They tutorials says options like influence and angular map but I don't see any of that.

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38992

Comment: Please consider [packing images in the blend file](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1336/is-there-any-way-to-save-background-images-in-the-blend-file/1337#1337) when using them anywhere. Regarding to the question I think you're talking about [environment texture](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8923/how-do-you-use-an-image-as-the-world-background) which you can easily add using adjacent node. Also  It's good idea to change Glossy shader to some other color except for black - reflections most likely won't be like that.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't know about the packing images thing. I tried that environment texture method and still I don't see the image, when I either render or am just viewing in the 3d view.

Comment: Is it shown when you press `Shift`+`Z`? DId you connect the Environment Texture node to the Background node ? Also could it be you use OpenCL to render HDR as [it's not supported](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-features-and-limitations)?

Comment: Yeah I've been toggling shift + Z constantly.  I got it to work actually.  I'm not sure what I did lol but I know that I was using rendered mode before, changed it to texture,and then when I put it back to rendered it worked.  I must've done something else.