# Noob - world color affecting rendered (plane) image

Tags: world

Just started with Blender yesterday, and already loving it.

Here's the blend I created mostly with a couple of youtube tuts. A simple PNG with transparancey, and a camera that tracks along a path while looking at the logo. http://simonandrewsphotography.com/db/index.php/s/ZqXFKXijql4odRj

Before rendering, everything looks fine, the logo text is purple. My problem is after it's rendered. When I set the world surface (world>surface>color) to orange (#FC7919), the purple text becomes a deep red. If I set the world surface color to white it's fine.

I'd also like to blend 2 shades of orange to make the background a little less boring.

Comment: Please upload blend files [here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), and edit your question to include screenshots as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that the world color does not only define the background, but also acts as a light source. When you set it to orange, you have a purple object illuminated with orange light, causing the red end result.
Using the white world color will illuminate it with white light, allowing the object to stay purple.

You could have a look [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56070/cycles-envirement-background-for-lighting-different-then-render-background) for a method to use a white lighting while having a colored background.

I've uploaded an example. The only changes I made that aren't directly visible when you open the file is that I enabled "Transparent" in the Film tab under the Render panel.

[image]

Comment: Please use this link to upload blend files: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. It guarantee files are preserved from behind erased in time.

Comment: That's great. Thanks for the speedy and informative response.