# Removing Glow From World Background

Tags: world

Im very new to modeling, and have what i hope will be a quick question.
I have been putting together a basic outdoor scene.
I changed the background colour to a sky blue colour as this seemed most appropriate.
The colour is fine, but the world background emits a glow which is somewhat out of place.

Is there a way to eliminate the glow from the background so as to just keep the colour?

Thanks for your time guys, it is very much appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the glow you mean? Do you use compositing nodes such as *Glare*?

Comment: You can change the strength of the world background, if that's what you mean. Alternatively, you can use HDRi for accurate outdoor lighting if you want.

Comment: @rjg Ive had a basic mess around with the nodes for the world background, though i think i may have done something wrong as i did not have a great deal of success.
I have attached a screenshot however to the original post however for reference. You will see that i have changed the background colour, but that objects in the scene are picking up a blue tint because of it.

Comment: @AshKB You are right, i could use a HDRi for this, but i wanted to try experimenting with just the inbuilt background stuff to see if i could get a result for cases where i just want a very basic solid colour background.

Comment: Even with the screenshot, it's unclear what "glow" you're referring to. Do you mean the fact that it lights up your object with a blue color? This is normal and you don't usually want to bypass it if your goal is realism. See this question for more info https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78267/noob-world-color-affecting-rendered-plane-image